Field inside a list of data using Selenium in Python
I have a python script, using selenium to automate a web page. I have a screen that shows a box where a list of cuits is located, the automation bot must search within those cuits for the one that matches a column called represented, then press the TAB key and go up or down with the keyboard until it finds the cuit that matches the one represented. However, I cannot get it to perform any action on that page. This is the structure:
import requests 
import json from selenium 
import webdriver from selenium.webdriver.common.by 
import By from selenium.webdriver.common.keys 
import Keys from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains 
import ActionChains import time from selenium.webdriver.support.ui 
import Select from selenium.webdriver.support.ui 
import WebDriverWait from selenium.webdriver.support 
import expected_conditions as EC 
import pandas as pd 
# Read the Excel file df = pd.read_excel(r"./data_clientes.xlsx") 
# Browser configuration driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
try: 
# Navigate to the page AFIP
driver.get("https://auth.afip.gob.ar/contribuyente_/login.xhtml")

# Iterate over each row of the DataFrame
for index, row in df.iterrows():
name = row['Name']
cuit = row['Cuit']
password = row['Password']
represented = row['Represented']

# Wait for the page to load
time.sleep(3)

# Find the CUIT field and send the CUIT
cuit_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, "F1:username")
cuit_input.clear()
cuit_input.send_keys(cuit)

# Find the "Next" button and click on it
next_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "F1:btnNext")
next_button.click()

# Wait a moment for the page to process the click
time.sleep(2)

# Find the key field and send the key
input_key = driver.find_element(By.ID, "F1:password")
input_key.clear()
input_key.send_keys(password)

# Submit the form
input_key.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Wait a moment to make sure the page has fully loaded
time.sleep(3)

# Find the search field on the AFIP home page
buscador_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, "buscadorInput")

# Enter "CCMA" in the search field
buscador_input.send_keys("CCMA")

# Submit the search form
buscador_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Wait a moment for the search to complete process
time.sleep(3)

# Select the "CCMA" element in the search results
ccma_elemento = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a/div/div/div[1]/div/p")
ccma_elemento.click()
time.sleep(10)
# If I am on a CCMA page with several representatives
# Check if we are on the CUIT selection page
if driver.current_url == "https://servicios2.afip.gob.ar/tramites_con_clave_fiscal/ccam/seleccionaCuit.asp":
cuit_representado=driver.find_element(By.ID, "representado")
cuit_representado.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
cuit_representado.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)

# enter the represented cuit
enter_cuit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/form/div[2]/input")
enter_cuit.click()
else:
continue
# Go to the login page for the next client
driver.get("https://auth.afip.gob.ar/contribuyente_/login.xhtml")

finally:
# Close the browser
driver.quit()

I would like the script to read and move with the keyboard to the searched cuit, then the automation process will continue.

Your code is not correctl formatted. When working with selenium DO NOT use arbitray sleep() calls. Use WebDriverWait which you can import from selenium.webdriver.support.ui
